# PowerShell `Select-String` selecting some but not others

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with a list of excel files in .xls and .xlsx formats. I have verified the strings exist in some of the files. When I run the below code, I can find some string patterns but not others. Example - I can find 'randomword' - but not '5625555555' or 'P-888452'. When I run `-NotMatch` on '5625555555' or 'P-888452' I do get a list of file names that do not match (although they return duplicated in many rows) so I know the pattern is registering. What could be happening here? Why is it playing nice with some string (it seems mostly letters) but no others (that contain integers).

```
gci "path" -Filter "*.xls" -Recurse -File | Select-String '\bANYTEXTORINT\b' | Select FileName
```

I also do not get an error when I run code. Just a return completed with white text and no results. I do get results for the 'randomword' though. Three files get returned that contain that pattern.

Comment: Excel files are not simple text files, so aren't going to behave nicely with `Select-String`.  For example, `.xlsx` files are really `.zip` archives with multiple XML files compressed inside - rename one to `.zip` and take a look.  Drop it into Notepad and see the 'text' it contains - that's what `Select-String` is searching, not the simple strings you might see when you open it in Excel.

Comment: Thank you @boxdog - I can def. see that. Would passing -Encoding of some format make any difference in the way it scans for the numbers I'm looking for?

Comment: Converting your excel into csv also would help, but its not possible if it contains multiple sheets.

Comment: @DillyB why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Csv will contain single sheet, excel may contain multiple sheets. Converting excel to CSV file will lead to lose other sheets in Excel file.(otherwise complex).